# Could not find the reference to GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET class

Tags: c, windows, device-driver

I am using MS VS2008 to build my application. I need to use "GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET " class to get the device interface list. But i could not find the reference  to this class. I have even tried in MS VS2015 but could not the reference.

Below is the code snippet.

```
ULONG DeviceListLength = 0;
cr = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_SizeW(&DeviceListLength,
                                        (LPGUID)&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET,
                                        NULL,
                                        CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);
```

Comment: Could you, at least, post your code?... [First Googled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545922%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: cr = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_SizeW(&DeviceListLength, (LPGUID)&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET, NULL, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);

Comment: Did you `#include <Ndisguid.h>` as reported at the page I linked?

Comment: I could not find Ndisguid.h header file in Visual studio default include path. So I have downloaded ndisguid.h but even in that file, I could not see NET class declaration

Comment: I'm not an expert, but as far as I can understand you need to download [Windows kits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg454513.aspx). Take a look.

Comment: I've gathered the device interface GUID's from the WDK 10 here: https://github.com/peterchen-cp/winapi-devinterface-ids

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft online documentation is not very detailed, but it does mention the header file `Ndisguid.h`. The filename might use a different case, but the Windows file system is not case-sensitive anyway:

```
#include <ndisguid.h>
```

references:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545922(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538471(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I could not find Ndisguid.h header file in Visual studio default include path. So I have downloaded ndisguid.h but even in that file, I could not see NET class declaration.

Comment: You should try Microsoft support directly.